# Are there any tools that can generate stubs in WCF based on a XSD?

Tags: .net, wcf, stubs

I'm currently writing a stub for a quoting service so that I can continue writing my application. I have a copy of the xsd that the service will request and respond with.

I was thinking about manually creating a WCF service which returns objects that are based on the XSD’s provided. The stub will use data from a configuration file to return the responses from the stub.

I’d like to use the same code to produce the mocks for the tests for that consumes the stub.

This feels like a problem that is common, Are there any tools that can generate stubs in wcf based on a XSD?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/concept.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soap UI is the tool, it even fits in to Continuous Integration nicely

Tried mocking bird, nice idea but its an incomplete tool

Thank you GTG